# How to make a 5 checkbox to be marked with values from databases

Tags: php, mysql, forms, checkbox

i want to make a form with 5 checkbox that will be retrieved from my table genres that contain(ID, name) of books (from database)-this works,  and i want to mark old genres from my table book_genre, this contain(ID,ID_book, ID_genre) and then to make an update with new genres - this did not work.

I did this:

```
                    <div>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="ID_gen<? echo $id=$row_genre_new['ID']; ?>" 
                                value="1" <? if($row_genre_old['ID_genre'] ) echo 'checked="checked"';  ?> />
                        <? echo $row_genre_new['name']; ?>
                    </div>  

                            <!--
                            <div>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="ID_gen<? echo $id=$row_genre_old['ID']; ?>" 
                                        value="1" checked="checked" />
                                    <? echo $row_genre_old['name']; ?>
                            </div>
                            -->

             <? } ?>
```

Comment: What exactly is not working in your code. Is there any error message that you are getting. Is that all the code you have ?

Comment: There's no error is just about logical. How i can compare if($row_genre_old['ID_genre']==$row_genre_new['ID'] ) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?>   every time is different because $row_genre_old['ID_genre'] (old genres from books) go from 2 and $row_genre_new['ID'] (all genres) go from 1 and then my loop through one less time towards $row_genre_new['ID']

Comment: Your example gives no indication as to how you are getting `$row_genre_new` and `$row_genre_old`. Please post the relevant code that populates these variables, which is likely where your issue is.

Comment: Ok you are right. I post another example with my code here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29247982/how-to-compare-2-table-in-a-loop

Answer (score 0):

You would loop through database results echoing a checkbox for each database entry with their id as the value and check whether it has been assigned in this case and if so echo checked

Comment: I do that , i loop through database but when i'm at if($row_genre_old['ID_genre']==$row_genre_new['ID'] ) echo 'checked="checked"';  ?> every time is different because $row_genre_old['ID_genre'] (old genres from books) go from 2 and $row_genre_new['ID'] (all genres) go from 1 and then my loop through one less time towards $row_genre_new['ID'] .

Comment: I don't know how to start my loop while( $row_genre_new = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_select_genre) ){ 
        $row_genre_old = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_genre_old);